# selenium-webdriver script isn't finding local file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to get a nodejs script loading Chrome to load a local file.

It works on 18.04 but not 22.04.

Has there been some significant change that would affect local file loading syntax, or is there something wrong in my code?

```
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver')

async function start() {
  const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
  const options = new chrome.Options()

  options.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  options.addArguments('--no-sandbox')

  const driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build()

  await driver.get('file://' + __dirname + '/myfile.html')
  await driver.sleep(10000)
  const text = await driver.executeScript('return document.documentElement.innerText')
  console.log(text)
  driver.quit()
}

start()
```

The result is:

```
Your file couldn’t be accessed

It may have been moved, edited or deleted.

ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I can confirm that `myfile.html` is definitely present.

Using console.log to show the file argument value shows it is the same for both older and newer Ubuntu.

Changing the driver.get argument to a website, e.g. https://www.google.com/ correctly shows the webpage content in the output.

The local file code fails as above using:

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Node v16.15.0
- chromium-browser Chromium 108.0.5359.71 snap

It works fine on:

- Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
- Node v16.15.0
- Chromium 107.0.5304.87 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because the default Ubuntu 22.04 Chrome package is a snap package that limits local file access to /home/ .

Switching to the .deb distribution from Google solves the issue. The Chromedriver also needs to match.

```
# Chrome browser - .deb package, not the standard OS Snap which limits access to only /home/
# See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home
# See: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome?dist=stable
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
apt-get update
apt-get install google-chrome-stable

# Chromedriver, matching version number
# See: https://skolo.online/documents/webscrapping/#pre-requisites
# See step 3 at: https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/
# See: https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/
#!# NB This will become out of sync if apt-get updates google-chrome-stable
google-chrome --version
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/108.0.5359.71/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
rm chromedriver_linux64.zip
```